# When I use catkin_make in my workspace i got errors. I use ROS indigo and ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

terminal output.

```
mk@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/mk/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/mk/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/mk/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/mk/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/mk/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/mk/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/mk/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/mk/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-
-  traversing 9 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - image_pipeline (metapackage)
-- ~~  - am_tutorial
-- ~~  - chapter2_tutorials
-- ~~  - camera_calibration
-- ~~  - image_proc
-- ~~  - image_view
-- ~~  - stereo_image_proc
-- ~~  - depth_image_proc
-- ~~  - image_rotate
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'image_pipeline'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_pipeline-indigo/image_pipeline)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'am_tutorial'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(am_tutorial)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'chapter2_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(chapter2_tutorials)
CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
/home/mk/catkin_ws/src/chapter2_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:46:
Parse error.  Expected "(", got identifier with text "messages".
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'camera_calibration'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_pipeline-indigo/camera_calibration)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'image_proc'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_pipeline-indigo/image_proc)
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'image_view'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_pipeline-indigo/image_view)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   signals
--   thread
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'stereo_image_proc'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_pipeline-indigo/stereo_image_proc)
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'depth_image_proc'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_pipeline-indigo/depth_image_proc)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'image_rotate'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_pipeline-indigo/image_rotate)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mk/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mk/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(chapter2_tutorials)
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

and my CMakelists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(chapter2_tutorials)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
 Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
 )
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES chapter2_tutorials
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
include_directories(
include
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(chap2_example1_a src/example1_a.cpp)
add_executable(chap2_example1_b src/example1_b.cpp)
add_dependencies(chap2_example1_a chapter2_tutorials_generate_
messages_cpp)
add_dependencies(chap2_example1_b chapter2_tutorials_generate_
messages_cpp)
target_link_libraries(chap2_example1_a ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(chap2_example1_b ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241864/hi-i-am-a-beginner-with-ros,-working-through-chapter-2-of-the-learning-ros-for-robotics-programming-book-(2nd-ed).when-i-use-catkin_make-in-my-workspace-i-got-errors.please-help-me.thank-you.i-use-ros-indigo-and-ubunto-14.0.4./) by [m.kowsar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27771/m.kowsar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the `CMakeLists.txt` you included is really a copy-paste, then I'm guessing the

```
 Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
```

and the

```
add_dependencies(chap2_example1_a chapter2_tutorials_generate_
messages_cpp)
add_dependencies(chap2_example1_b chapter2_tutorials_generate_
messages_cpp)
```

lines are confusing CMake (notice the line-breaks).

The first line ("Generate added messages ..") was originally a comment (so either remove it completely or put back the `#` in front of it), and the other two commands (`add_dependencies(..)`) should not be broken up into two lines (ie: each `add_dependencies(..)` should be on a single line).

---

Edit:

> i said that use hapter 2 of the Learning ROS for Robotics Programming book (2nd ed) so my CMAke is a copy paste file. The line "Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here" come in book and  ROS.org then can't be comment.

The book has probably wrapped some lines to make the `CMakeLists.txt` fit better in the overal layout of the text. The `add_dependencies(..)` lines *cannot* be split like you have it now. They **must** be a single line each.

As to the "Generate added messages and services with [..]" line: it doesn't matter what the book has there, that line is not a valid CMake command, so has to be removed: either delete it entirely, or make it a comment by prefixing it with a hash (`#`).

> my problem did not solved.

If you changed things in your `CMakeLists.txt` and it still doesn't work, please update your original question with the adjusted `CMakeLists.txt` and any (new) errors you get.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [m.kowsar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27771/m.kowsar/) on 2016-08-20**:
thank you gvdhoorn.i said that use hapter 2 of the Learning ROS for Robotics Programming book (2nd ed) so my CMAke is a copy paste file.The line "Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here" come in book and  ROS.org then can't be comment.my problem did not solved.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-20**:
Btw: it seems like [this](https://github.com/AaronMR/Learning_ROS_for_Robotics_Programming_2nd_edition) repository holds the accompanying code for the book you mentioned. Can you compare your `CMakeLists.txt` to the one in that repository?